# SSIS Convert string to DateTime dd/mm/yyy hh:mm:ss

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I want to convert a string like **"2152012 101946"** using a derived column in SSIS.

The output should be like **"21/05/2012 10:19:46"** to fit into a **[DateTime]** SQL Server 2008 field

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should think about enriching your date time data . You need to have a proper format like

> YYYYMMDD HH:MM::SS

or something similar to it . You just can't have

> YYYYMDD HH:MM:SS

If you have your data in the correct format DDMMYYY HH:MM:SS then you can use the below expression in derived column

```
LEN(column) == 0 ? NULL(DT_DBTIMESTAMP) :
(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(substring(column,1,2) + "-" + substring(column,3,2) + "-" +
substring(column,5,4) + " " + substring(column,10,2) + ":" substring(column,12,2)+ ":"
+ substring(column,14,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

DT_DBTIMESTAMP data types must be in the following format for proper conversion:

> YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

Using the date & time "2012-07-30 02:03:10" as an example, your derived column would appear as:

```
(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(SUBSTRING([column],1,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING([column],5,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING([column],7,2) + " " + SUBSTRING([column],9,2) + ":" + SUBSTRING([column],11,2) + ":" + SUBSTRING([column],13,2))
```

The resulting output column would appear as:

> 2012-07-30 02:03:10.000

Recall that any missing values within a given date can be concatenated with the date values within your column. For example, using the string value "2152012 101946", your derived column expression would be written as:

```
(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(SUBSTRING([column],4,4) + "- 0" + SUBSTRING([column],3,1) + "-" + SUBSTRING([column],1,2) + " " + SUBSTRING([column],9,2) + ":" + SUBSTRING([column],11,2) + ":" + SUBSTRING([column],13,2) + ".000")
```

Taking this one step further, since dates in string format often are not clean, you might consider writing a conditional statement which checks the length of a value prior to concatenating & converting the values. For example, if 2012/09/30 11:59pm and 2012/10/01 11:59pm are represented as strings in a column where leading zeros are not present, the strings may appear as:

"2012930 115959"
"20121001 115959"

To account for leading zeros in the month, an if-then-else expression could be incorporated such that:

```
LEN(column) = 14 ? (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(SUBSTRING([column],1,4) + "- 0" + SUBSTRING([column],5,1) + "-" + SUBSTRING([column],6,2) + " " + SUBSTRING([column],9,2) + ":" + SUBSTRING([column],11,2) + ":" + SUBSTRING([column],13,2)) : (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(SUBSTRING([column],1,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING([column],5,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING([column],7,2) + " " + SUBSTRING([column],10,2) + ":" + SUBSTRING([column],12,2) + ":" + SUBSTRING([column],14,2))
```

*Note that the above expression does not take values that have a length less than 14 characters or greater than 15 characters into account. In this case, you could expand the above if-then-else expression to nest additional expressions for varying lengths.*